# Folder name in path variable is repeated

Tags: shell-script, variable, tomcat

I am fairly new to linux and have been facing this issue and was wondering if something can help resolve it. 
So when I try to shutdown Tomcat, this is the error I am getting. As you can see 'bin' is repeated in the path. I can see that its picking up the wrong path but not sure what variable needs to be modified as I checked $JAVA_HOME and $PATH, and they seem to be fine.

```
bash-4.1$ ./shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /apps/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /apps/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apps/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin
Using CLASSPATH:       /apps/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/bin/bootstrap.jar:/apps/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
/apps/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/bin/catalina.sh: line 467: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Also, the checked like 467 and this is what it says which I am not sure what to make. This is how it looks like:

```
   466
    467   eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS \
    468     -Djava.endorsed.dirs="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
    469     -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
```

Also here's what PATH and JAVA_HOME look like.

```
bash-4.1$ echo $JAVA_HOME
:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/java

bash-4.1$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/vzwhome/mehtta4/bin:/apps/opt/databuck/opt/bin:/apps/opt/databuck/opt/node/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/vzwhome/mehtta4/bin:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/java
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `$JRE_HOME` to the value without `bin`? I don't know much about Java, but `HOME` perhaps sounds like it's expecting to be a sort of top-level directory, not a `bin` directory inside it.

Comment: The problem is where it calculates the `RUNJAVA` value. Can you [edit] your question to include this passage?

Comment: @Celada I did use the $JRE_HOME without. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your `JRE_HOME` variable contains the path `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin` and that `catalina.sh` is using `$JRE_HOME/bin/java` as the full path to the `java` executable.

`$JRE_HOME/bin/java` will expand to `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/bin/java` which can not be found.

It is likely that `JRE_HOME` should be set to `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_121` rather than to `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin`.

There is an [answer with a comment over at StackOverflow that confirms this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28489493/4941495), and that goes on to say that if `JRE_HOME` is unset, the value of `JAVA_HOME` will be used instead.